# Odoo preview of attached document?

Tags: preview, openerp-7, document-management, knowledge-management, odoo

Hallo is there any module to have a preview of a document attached in Odoo document management, without having to download it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It depends what filetype you are talking about (pdf?), and it depends the browser plugins you have installed/enabled.

If you are talking about opening pdfs in a new browser window, you have to configure your browser for that and make sure that the acrobat reader browser plugin is activated for that browser.

Also, every document you ever see on your computer is downloaded one way or another. Whether it is in temporary internet files or on your desktop. So, avoiding to "download" is not possible, but I'm assuming that you refer to "downloading to a temporary location".

Comment: Thank you, from your answer I see you focus more on the client side than the server side.
At the time I asked this question (one year ago) I was more thinking of something like a JQuery PDF viewer/previewer